# "ValueError: operation parameter must be str"

Tags: python, csv, sqlite

```
import csv
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users')
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE  users (Nom TEXT,Prenom TEXT,Date de naissance DATE,Fonction TEXT,Departement TEXT,Courriel TEXT,Telephone varchar(15)) ')
connection.commit()

csvfile = open('data.csv',"rt")
creader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')

t = 0
for t in creader:
    cursor.execute(('INSERT INTO users VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', t))

csvfile.close()
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Since 20 min I am blocked on line 16 of my script. **This is the entire code without the comments (Daniel)**

I want to add values ​​to my database iteratively with the for loop using the separator ","

The generated error is:

> line 16, in  cursor.execute(('INSERT INTO users VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', t,)) ValueError: operation parameter must be str

Extract from csv:

```
Nom;Prenom;Date de naissance;Fonction;Departement;Courriel;Telephone
DOE;John;10/10/1950;Directeur;Direction;john@doe.com;01 02 03 04 05
```

Maybe my csv file is corrupted?

Full Traceback: [image]

Comment: That appears to be line 16, not line 23. Please show your actual code and full traceback.

Comment: Code and traceback updated :)

Comment: An extract of the contents of data.csv would also be helpful. Also: why `t=0`?

Comment: I thought the error came from this variable and had to initialize it to "0" before using it

Comment: You still need to post the full traceback. And as Christian says it would be useful to see some of the data.

Comment: I understand for the delimiter and for the first line thank you. But after changing the delimiter the same error is generated at line 16 "ValueError: operation parameter must be str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your csv exerpt the delimiter should obviously be `;`.

Also you would always import the header (`Nom; Prenom;...`) into your database, maybe you should skip the first line of the csv-file.

The problem is in the line

```
cursor.execute(('INSERT INTO users VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', t))
```

Exchange the double `((` and `))` - then everything works fine. `t` is a list of strings, (t) is a set containing one list.

Comment: Wonderful. You could mark my answer as accepted then (clicking the check mark on the left). ;-)